# Charm to promote hair growth Atharva veda

Tags: vedas, mantras, translation-request, atharva-veda

Please someone translate the following mantras of Atharva veda Book 6- hymn 21, hymn 30,31, hymn 136,137 to English prose from Sanskrit?

As I don't know sanskrit. I read online that they promote hair growth.

- How to chant these mantras? or
- What is the complete procedure to recite it effectively?

Comment: Pronounciation, which God/Goddess is this mantra and various other things association along with pronounciation is important...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the hymns of Atharvana Veda Book 6 pertaining to hair growth in Sanskrit, along with links to their English translations:

[Book 6 Hymn 21: A charm to strengthen hair and promote its growth](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av06021.htm)

> imā́ yā́s tisráḥ pr̥tʰivī́s tā́sāṃ ha bʰū́mir uttamā́ |
>
> tā́sām ádʰi tvacó aháṃ bʰeṣajáṃ sám u jagrabʰam ||
>
> śréṣṭʰam asi bʰeṣajā́nāṃ vásiṣṭʰaṃ vī́rudʰānām |
>
> sómo bʰága iva yā́meṣu devéṣu váruṇo yátʰā ||
>
> révatīr ánādʰr̥ṣaḥ siṣāsávaḥ siṣāsatʰa |
>
> utá stʰá keśadŕ̥ṁhaṇīr átʰo ha keśavárdʰanīḥ ||

[Book 6 Hymn 30: A charm to promote the growth of hair](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av06030.htm)

> devā́ imáṃ mádʰunā sáṃyutaṃ yávaṃ sárasvatyām ádʰi maṇā́v acarkr̥ṣuḥ |
>
> índra āsīt sī́rapatiḥ śatákratuḥ kīnā́śā āsan marútaḥ sudā́navaḥ ||
>
> yás te mádo 'vakeśó vikeśó yénābʰihásyaṃ púruṣaṃ kr̥ṇóṣi |
>
> ārā́t tvád anyā́ vánāni vr̥kṣi tváṃ śami śatávalśā ví roha ||
>
> bŕ̥hatpalāśe súbʰage várṣavr̥ddʰa ŕ̥tāvari |
>
> mātéva putrébʰyo mr̥ḍa kéśebʰyaḥ śami ||

[Book 6 Hymn 136: A charm to promote the growth of hair](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av06136.htm)

> devī́ devyā́m ádʰi jātā́ pr̥tʰivyā́m asy oṣadʰe |
>
> tā́ṃ tvā nitatni kéśebʰyo dŕ̥ṃhaṇāya kʰanāmasi ||
>
> dŕ̥ṃha pratnā́n janáyā́jātān jātā́n u várṣīyasas kr̥dʰi ||
>
> yás te kéśo 'vapádyate sámūlo yáś ca vr̥ścáte |
>
> idáṃ táṃ viśvábʰeṣajyābʰí ṣiñcāmi vīrúdʰā ||

[Book 6 Hymn 137: A charm to promote the growth of hair](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av06137.htm)

> yā́ṃ jamádagnir ákʰanad duhitré keśavárdʰanīm |
>
> tā́ṃ vītáhavya ā́bʰarad ásitasya gr̥hébʰyaḥ ||
>
> abʰī́śunā méyā āsan vyāménānuméyāḥ |
>
> kéśā naḍā́ iva vardʰantāṃ śīrṣṇás te asitā́ḥ pári ||
>
> dŕ̥ṃha mū́lam ā́graṃ yacʰa ví mádʰyaṃ yāmayauṣadʰe |
>
> kéśā naḍā́ iva vardʰantām śīrṣṇás te asitā́ḥ pári ||

Note that the proper use of Vedic mantras is discussed in the Brahmanas of the Vedas, but Gopatha Brahmana of the Atharvana Veda in Sanskrit is only [available in Sanskrit](http://archive.org/download/gopathabrahmanao00gopauoft/gopathabrahmanao00gopauoft_bw.pdf) as far as I can tell.

And more importantly, as others have pointed out chanting these mantras on your own without someone (a Guru or priest) to instruct you in person on proper procedure is vanishingly unlikely to lead to the positive effects you're looking for, and it may well lead to negative effects.  So this answer is for informational purposes only, not a guide on how to do it.

Comment: Thank You so much! I will ask a priest about what you said. and again thank you for replying and informing me!

Comment: Is there any Mantra to get body strength?

Comment: Do you have any youtube links to these chants that I could follow for pronunciation?

Answer (score 4):

Chanting of mantras such as these must be done in Sanskrit to be effective. Chanting them in English is of no consequence. The intonations in Sanskrit must be done correctly or they may have a detrimental and sometimes opposite effect. It is best to get the assistance of a Brahmin priest who is well versed in the Atharva Veda. Not all are.

Comment: Thank you sir for responding! I just want them written inenglish or hindi or telugu. example= नारा शार्दुला = nara Sharadula= Tigerly man. I don't know how to ask in person so that's why I asked in here. if that mantras goin to help then please tell me how to chant it( i mean if there is particular time and any rules).

Answer (score 1):

Before starting "chanting" or repeating mentally (manasa japa) a mantra, you should learn basically the rules for correct pronunciation of sanskrit letters and combination of them. So you should know the differences from a short vocal or a long one (u for example has a short form and can form the hu.m seed-mantra also has a long form and can form huu.m mantra, which denotes another form of energy or deity). I use Velthuis system above for transliteration to mark such a distinctive vowel use. Then there are combinations of vowels like a+u=o, a+i=e in some mantra. Then there are other consonants and semi-vowels. After you have this basic knowledge (which contains visarga .h, used as last sign in some mantra, and .m used also in the end of some common seed-mantra) you can start practicing.

Comment: For the record, we welcome all points of view on this site, but you shouldn't express opinions that aren't relevant to answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not fit in the exact context of the question, but it relates to cure for hairloss and baldness.

There is a Vidhi in Tantra called Atharva Veedhi. Before chanting a mantra name of it's 'Chanda', 'Hrishi', associated 'Deity' are uttered and then the wish is uttered.

This way of chanting is highly effective in fulfilling the wish.

Thus a potential mantra Vidhi using 'Om ekakshar(single syllabul) mantra 'for hairloss n baldness cure can be as follows....

ओमकार मंत्रः गायत्री छंद: परमात्मा नारायण ह्रिषि: (Hrisheehee) अंतर्यामी देवता । मम शिर केश पतन शमनार्थे शिरे नूतन केशा: उत्पत्ती अर्थे जपे विनीयोग: ।

Please let me know what you guys think about my above thoughts of using Atharva Mantra Vidhi for hairloss n baldness... All views n opinions are most welcome.